# TemplateUrl в роутинге на angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый день, в роутинге `angularjs` работает шаблон с локального сайта

```
templateUrl: 'templates/Students.html',
```

А вот если написать c другого сайта, например

```
templateUrl: 'http://Mysite.com/templates/Students.html', то ничего не работает.
```

Открываю "в лоб" обе ссылки- они одинаковые. Исходный код - тоже. В чём тут может быть прикол? Я что-то не понимаю.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю потому что параметр `templateUrl` обрабатывает только относительные маршруты, а `http://` обрабатывать не умеет, это сразу исключает попытки юзеров подключить шаблон с другого сайта